# Too many SSTables are created after running nodetool repair and the SStable is not compacting

Tags: cassandra-2.0, repair, nodetool

I have 4 node in a data center with a replication factor 3. While running nodetool repair in a node too many SSTables are generated but the file size is very less (around 4KB). This issues had been reported earlier by someone else in the link given below. But for us, compaction does not trigger even after 2 weeks of time and remains with so many sstables (about 10k). We are using the size-tiered-compaction and cassandra version is 2.0.3.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6698

Please let me know, if you need any further details.

Comment: Try asking here? http://dba.stackexchange.com/